# Wordpress creating custom theme-Reusability

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, themes, reusability

first approach to CMS and wordpress I'm wondering if there's any predefined html structure and classes/IDs "must-be" reference that I can refer for making my own theme willing to change in the future for another wordpress theme

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't require you to have any specific classes or IDs in your theme in terms of the HTML and CSS, the only things WP needs are things like the wp_head function inside your  element on every page. Having said that themes such as [Starkers](http://starkerstheme.com/) were created to enable developers to have a starting point instead of starting from scratch.

Now the above applies only to whatever code *you* write, there are however some functions in WP that will return standard code, for instance if you don't specifically create the comment thread code, WP will generate it for you, and that is really the only code that many themes will share.

I would say that if you are intending on making a number of blogging themes for instance, having a set of standard code might be a good idea, for the article pages for example, so that you don't have to re-write code over and over. Aside from that the only code I ever reuse when making themes is the CSS to style comments if I don't hand-code the comments section, this is a good idea as it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: so if I understand wordpress exctracts content from whatever structure is in..and builds whatever structure i want around it?

Comment: Wordpress uses a series of functions such as 'the_title()' to display content in whatever structure you like, it's like WP is the brain and your structure is the body.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other 'template' themes that could get you started - if Starkers isn't quite your thing, you might find [WP Framework](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/wp-framework) a good alternative. Or - just start stripping down the Twenty Eleven theme to give you a base (which is just what the Starkers theme does, using the Twenty Ten theme as a base).

There's also quite a handy first-time guide on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) around theme development if you'd prefer to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provide some functions which add CSS classes depending of page type, templete, conditional tags . . .etc.

These functions are `body_class()` and `post_class()`.

For more info check:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class